# SQL Query that leaves duplicate fields blank?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

What I would like is if my data is this:

```
ID     Name
0      Jim
1      Dave
1      Bob
1      John
2      Ann
```

My query returns this:

```
ID     Name
0      Jim
1      Dave
       Bob
       John
2      Ann
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

**Edit:**

The query which returns the original 2 columns of data would be something like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This is much easier on the client side.  In sql you have to join back to the same list offset by one and then do an if.

Comment: oh... you could do it with a recursive cte on sql servers that support it.  ms-access does not support that.

Comment: If you're going to display the data on a report, the Access Report Wizard can let you group by certain fields and only display the particular data once. Outside of that, you can't really do it from Access SQL

Comment: Alright thanks for the responses. I'm dumping results into an HTML table so maybe I'll just have some javascript that'll deal with this for me.